# Pylance not recognizing venv libraries

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

My VS Code and some components have auto-updated this week and Pylance stopped recognizing my virtual enviroment (venv) libraries.

`Import "xxxx" could not be resolved Pylance(ReportMissingImports)` .

**What happens**

→ On VS Code startup it tries to run Activate.ps1 for my venv but it gives an error due to privilege issues (UnauthorizedAccess)

→ Even though it gives this error, the venv is set as the current interpreter, thus running the code works perfectly and it uses the correct venv

My guess is that, in this last update, they started using the terminal's python instead of using the selected interpreter python. Since the activation does not work, the python used is not the correct one and it is not able to recognize the modules giving the error above.

What I am trying to find is if there is a way to force Pylance to use the venv via `settings.json` or if it is possible to solve this issue in another way.